# Read Timeouts in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have 8 node cassandra cluster with 4 in each DC. 1 DC is used for read s and other DC is used for writes. The writes are kicked in with jobs which loads the data into the cluster. During the data load we see read timeouts for the Read Application, and also long GC pauses of more that 20 seconds for the servers in write Datacenter. I suspect the issue is due to Young GC pauses, because there are many collections for Young generation. How can fix both the Timeouts and long GC pauses. I had allocated 10 GB to Young Generation and 10 GB to Old Generation.

Things done till now:

- Increased Heap size from 12 GB to 20 GB.
- Stop auto compaction for the keyspaces
- Reduced ParallelGCThreads to 32
- Increased MaxTenuringThreshold to 6

Thanks,

Comment: what version of Cassandra, what is the version of Java, what driver is used to load data, what are the read requests, what consistency levels are used for reads & writes?

Comment: Cassandra Version: 3.11.1, Java version: 1.8.0_181, Driver : Datastax Java driver,Read Consistency : One, Write Consistency : Local_One. Type of Read requests: Webcalls from API

Comment: Any body has some insight on this issue. The writes are done using Java program where it parses the csv files and writes to cassandra.